# laravel updating error -Whoops, looks like something went wrong

Tags: php, laravel-5

While i updating user form:

```
FatalThrowableError in Manager.php line 77:
    Type error: Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Support\Manager::createDriver(), 0 passed in /var/www/greenguru/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Manager.php on line 87 and exactly 1 expected
```

Comment: Show some code, only the error is not very usefull

Comment: thanks bro for your comment i fixed the error, that was in env file ..

Comment: that's good to hear, but it would be usefull to answer your own question with the solution you have found, so other people in the future will know the answer to your problem too.

Comment: CACHE_DRIVER=array
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync
REDIRECT=http://localhost/callback, i added this in env file